# wpf ListView - disable header mouse over effect

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

I have a simple 1 column ListView and I need to disable the mouse over effect for the GridViewColumnHeader.

I tried grabbing the style from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747.aspx

However that gave my header a purple gradient so I guess it was the wrong style. I do notice it has a

```
<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
```

But I have no idea how to remove that without finding and including the correct GridViewColumnHeader style and then removing it.

I tried the following, but it doesn't do anything (The VisualState overrides?) and wouldn't work anyway as setting the background to null wouldn't be what I want.

```
       <Style x:Key="hcs" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, like you said yourself, in MouseOver visual state and its Storyboard. I think it`s better to get rid from redundant functionality than try to override it later. So we basically just need the same style but without that storyboard. For bare minimum we need to have following things (can be found on MSDN via the link you provided):

```
 <Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
 <Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

 <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper"
           TargetType="Thumb">
      <!-- Full GridViewColumnHeaderGripper style here  -->
 </Style>

 <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
              <!-- Standard template but with redundant Storyboard removed -->
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
```

The last Style doesn`t have a key so it applies to all `GridViewColumnHeader` on page \ application (depends on where it is defined). Or you can set the key and use it only in specific grids.

That`s bare minimum so for more customizable approach it may be better to copy other parts of default style too.